# Setting a dynamic variable from a method to Oninit

Tags: typescript, angular6

Processing a variable by an event by a method and wants to set it whenever the component initializes

```
options = [ //array that holds dropdown's options
{ name: "All Countries", value: '/allcountries' },
{ name: "India", value: '/india' }
]

i=0; //initializing variable 'i'
onCountrySelect($event) { //method that gets the dropdown value's array position 
this.i=$event.target.options.selectedIndex; //getting the event in 'i'
}

ngOnInit(){
this.selectedOption = this.options[this.i].name; //i want to set that 
variable 'i' here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the sessionStorage. You could do it like this:

```
options = [ //array that holds dropdown's options
    { name: "All Countries", value: '/allcountries' },
    { name: "India", value: '/india' }
]

i: number = 0;

onCountrySelect($event) { 
    this.i=$event.target.options.selectedIndex;
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedCountry', JSON.stringify(this.i));
}

ngOnInit(){
    const temp = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedCountry');

    if(temp) {
        this.i = JSON.parse(temp);
    } 

    this.selectedOption = this.options[this.i].name;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`. The difference is, that `sessionStorage` will be erased as soon as you close the current browser tab. Whereas `localStorage` will be present until you clean up your cookies 'n stuff.

EDIT:

***Option 2***

Build a service containing your variable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {
   private selectedCountry: number = 0;

   constructor() { }

   setSelectedCountry(value: number): void {
       this.selectedCountry = value;
   }

   getSelectedCountry(): number {
       return this.selectedCountry;
   }
}
```

You have to import the service into your Module and provide it.

```
import { ComponentA } from './component-a.ts';
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ComponentA
  ],
  imports: [
    ComponentA
  ],
  providers: [
      SimpleService
  ]

})
export class XYZModule { }
```

Then your component sets the value and gets it.

ComponentA

```
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service.ts';

constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) { }

onCountrySelect($event) { 
    this.i=$event.target.options.selectedIndex;
    this.simpleService.setSelectedCountry(this.i);
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.i = this.simpleService.getSelectedCountry();        
    this.selectedOption = this.options[this.i].name;
}
```

Whatever option you prefer, you have to be a little verbose when it comes to code. There is no one-liner, though.

Comment: Is there any way rather than session storage?

Comment: Of course. You could use a service and put the value there. Gimme 5 more mins.

Comment: Here you go. Please find above a solution using a service.

Comment: Okay Thanks & Have a nice day :-)